# How to use delegates in Razor pages

Tags: c#, web, razor

so: I have this library that I'm using, and a particular method requires a callback to work, however I am clueless as to how I can get this information.

```
@{
MyLibrary.Connect("myEmail", "myPassword", delegate(Client client)
{
    <h3>Connected</h3>
}, delegate (Error error)
{
    <h3>error: @error</h3>
});
```

}

This is what I'm trying to attempt, but unable to do as it throws errors.
[image]

Comment: You are probably missing a reference to the necessary class. The code would even compile as you are missing a `)`. What's the error message when you hover on any of the squiggles?

Comment: I edited out what the library was for this example.